# in searchbar code data is getting undefined in filter function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import JSONDATA from "./MOCK_DATA.json";
function App() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search..."
        onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
      />
      {JSONDATA.filter((val) => {
        if (searchTerm === "") {
          return val;
        } else if (
          val.first_name
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchTerm.first_name.toLowerCase())
        ) {
          return val;
        }
      }).map((val, key) => (
        <div className="user" key={key}>
          <p>{val.first_name}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

MOCK_DATA.json

```
[{"id":1,"first_name":"Jewel","last_name":"Galton","email":"jgalton0@merriam-webster.com","date_of_birth":"19/12/1974","age":19,"country":"China","phone":"8122493249"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Margaret","last_name":"Houndsom","email":"mhoundsom1@cyberchimps.com","date_of_birth":"01/05/1975","age":43,"country":"Gambia","phone":"4218624730"},
{"id":3,"first_name":"Toby","last_name":"Dussy","email":"tdussy2@weibo.com","date_of_birth":"03/08/2007","age":48,"country":"Brazil","phone":"5208765150"},
{"id":4,"first_name":"Stormy","last_name":"Abrahamoff","email":"sabrahamoff3@spotify.com","date_of_birth":"17/11/1984","age":31,"country":"Panama","phone":"4992469147"},
{"id":5,"first_name":"Saundra","last_name":"MacRinn","email":"smacrinn4@simplemachines.org","date_of_birth":"17/02/1976","age":33,"country":"Philippines","phone":"8446151525"}
]
```

when i execute the above code in browser and type in search input i am getting error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')

i don't understand why it is not working can you tellme what is wrong here

Comment: Try `searchTerm.toLowerCase()` insted of `searchTerm.first_name.toLowerCase()`, searchTerm is string not object

Comment: thanks so much i havent checked it like that